# How to convert records in a table to xml format using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I've got a simple table and want to store its content into a xml on the harddrive. There should be one root element for the whole table, one element per table row and one child element per table column.

What possibilities do I have?

Thanks a lot
Tomas

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use the **FOR XML** in your query.

E.g: `select * from table1 FOR XML AUTO`

see this --> http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1265579,00.html

Alternatively, you can create your own XML in your t-sql code through cursors or in your application code, the longer way of doing it.

Comment: The link in this answer requires membership to view.

Answer (score 54):

And if you need more control over how the resulting XML looks like, check out the new **`FOR XML PATH`** statement in SQL Server 2005 and newer.

A statement like this (based on the infamous `Northwind` database):

```
SELECT 
   CustomerID as "@CustomerID",
   CompanyName,
   Address as "address/street",
   City as "address/city",
   Region as "address/region",
   PostalCode as "address/zip",
   Country as "address/country",
   ContactName as "contact/name",
   ContactTitle as "contact/title",
   Phone as "contact/phone", 
   Fax as "contact/fax"
FROM Customers
FOR XML PATH('Customer')
```

will result in an output like this:

```
  <Customer CustomerID="ALFKI">
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
    <address>
      <street>Obere Str. 57</street>
      <city>Berlin</city>
      <zip>12209</zip>
      <country>Germany</country>
    </address>
    <contact>
      <name>Maria Anders</name>
      <title>Sales Representative</title>
      <phone>030-0074321</phone>
      <fax>030-0076545</fax>
    </contact>
  </Customer>
```

That's rather tricky to get any other way....

Marc

Comment: How do I do the reverse i.e. convert XML back to a table

Comment: @RaihanIqbal: look at the built-in XQuery support in T-SQL - using `.query()`, `.nodes()` and `.value()`, you can definitely do that - but that's a whole different question :-)

Comment: This is good stuff!  I'd only add that the Questioner wanted "one root element for the whole table".  To do this, simply add `ROOT('Root')` like so:  `FOR XML PATH('Customer'), ROOT('Customers')`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CAST('1' AS XML)`

**This Query fire in sql and your copy data put inside then show XML Result.**