# how to save for xml query result from database

Tags: sql-server, xml, linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on mvc4. I am stuck with problem where i need to save table data a xml.

my sp code is as belows

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetXMLForClient] 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * from tbl_tablename where lng_clientid=1
for xml path,root('tablename ')
END
```

It returns xml file but when i try to get this file i am getting error that

```
 function evaluation timed out
Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation
```

code i am using to get sp result is

```
var res = Context.usp_GetXMLForClient();
```

How can i solve this problem.

Please advise

Comment: Try this.
SELECT * from tbl_tablename where lng_clientid=1
for XML AUTO

Comment: but it generate different type of xml ...i need row wise row with 1 root element.. thats why i used for xml path,root('tablename ')...

Comment: It may help you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564541/how-to-convert-records-in-a-table-to-xml-format-using-t-sql

Comment: running query on sql : how much time it would take ?