# SQL Table result in a xml output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, sqlxml

I have a table

```
Key     code 
1       100
1       200
1       300
1       400
2       100
2       200
2       300
```

I am looking for my result in one row with key and other row XML_data

```
Key      XML_Data(XML column)
1        <sub><key>1...
2        <sub><key>2...
```

XML_Data example :

```
<sub>
  <key> 1 </Key>
    <list>
      <code> 100 </code>
      <code> 200 </code>
      <code> 300 </code>
      <code> 400 </code>
   </list>
</sub>
```

Thanks

Comment: The query you've tried so far is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite fuzzy, but my magic crystall ball tells me, that you are looking for this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Key] INT, code INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
 (1,100)
,(1,200)
,(1,300)
,(1,400)
,(2,100)
,(2,200)
,(2,300);
```

--The query will first find a distinct list of keys and then use nested `FOR XML`-selects to gather your data into the structure wanted:

```
WITH DistinctKeys AS
(SELECT [Key] FROM @tbl GROUP BY [Key])
SELECT dk.[Key]
      ,(
        SELECT dk.[Key]
              ,(
                SELECT t.code
                FROM @tbl AS t
                WHERE t.[Key]=dk.[Key]
                FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('list'),TYPE
               )
        FOR XML PATH('sub'),TYPE    
       ) AS XML_Data
FROm DistinctKeys AS dk
```

The result

```
Key XML_Data
1   <sub><Key>1</Key><list><code>100</code><code>200</code><code>300</code><code>400</code></list></sub>
2   <sub><Key>2</Key><list><code>100</code><code>200</code><code>300</code></list></sub>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this [SQL Server: Two-level GROUP BY with XML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132039/sql-server-two-level-group-by-with-xml-output) it's closer.

*Posted here because i don't have reputation for comment.*

Answer (score 0):

You've not specified much, as to where your XML is etc. but in general following query should help in your case.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
  (key, xml_data) 
VALUES 
  (KEY, CONVERT(XML, N'YOUR_XML', 2));
```

You can go even further with that, by declaring XML as variable, extracing your KEY from XML, and to 2nd column adding XML based on whole variable.

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<sub>
  <key> 1 </key>
    <list>
      <code> 100 </code>
      <code> 200 </code>
      <code> 300 </code>
      <code> 400 </code>
   </list>
</sub>'

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(key, xml_data)
   SELECT
      key = COALESCE(XCol.value('key[1]', 'int'),0),
      xml_data = CONVERT(XML, N''''+@input+'''', 2)
   FROM  @input.nodes('/sub') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

**@ATC**, thank you for your comment. If really what is needed is to get table into XML format please try following - **FOR XML PATH** is what you're looking for

```
SELECT 
   key,
   code as "list/code"
FROM dbo.YourTable
FOR XML PATH('sub')
```

I'm not able to test it right now unfortunately.
Here you can see similar question: [How to convert records in a table to xml format using T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564541/how-to-convert-records-in-a-table-to-xml-format-using-t-sql)

Comment: Your updated query will not lead to the structure the OP states in his question...

Comment: @Shnugo thanks for comment, unfortunately I'm not able to do real testing due to my pc / environment limitation. It was more like a concept to take further. Seen your answer, seems like it will solve the problem well, thanks!