# Converting rows to XML format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I have requirement like below.

[image]

And ddl and dml script for above image is

```
CREATE TABLE #example
    ([CCP_DETAILS_SID] int, [ACCOUNT_GROWTH] int, [PRODUCT_GROWTH] int, [PROJECTION_SALES] numeric(22,6), [PROJECTION_UNITS] numeric(22,6), [PERIOD_SID] int)
;

INSERT INTO #example
    ([CCP_DETAILS_SID], [ACCOUNT_GROWTH], [PRODUCT_GROWTH], [PROJECTION_SALES], [PROJECTION_UNITS], [PERIOD_SID])
VALUES
    (30001, 0, 0, 1505384.695, 18487.25251, 1801),
    (30001, 0, 0, 1552809.983, 18695.75536, 1802),
    (30001, 0, 0, 1595642.121, 18834.75725, 1803),
    (30002, 0, 0, 10000.32, 18834.75725, 1801),
    (30002, 0, 0, 1659124.98, 18834.75725, 1802),
    (30002, 0, 0, 465859546.6, 18834.75725, 1803)
;
```

And i have to convert above results to xml format like below (Output).

```
ccp_details_sid           xml_format_string

30001                      <period>  
                           <period_sid period_sid=1801>
                           <PROJECTION_SALES>1505384.695</PROJECTION_SALES>
                           <PROJECTION_UNITS>18487.25251<PROJECTION_UNITS>
                           <ACCOUNT_GROWTH>0</ACCOUNT_GROWTH>
                           <PRODUCT_GROWTH>0</PRODUCT_GROWTH>
                           </period_sid>
                            <period_sid period_sid=1802>
                           <PROJECTION_SALES>1552809.983</PROJECTION_SALES>
                           <PROJECTION_UNITS>18695.75536<PROJECTION_UNITS>
                           <ACCOUNT_GROWTH>0</ACCOUNT_GROWTH>
                           <PRODUCT_GROWTH>0</PRODUCT_GROWTH>
                           </period_sid>
                           <period_sid period_sid=1802>
                           <PROJECTION_SALES>1595642.121</PROJECTION_SALES>
                           <PROJECTION_UNITS>18834.75725<PROJECTION_UNITS>
                           <ACCOUNT_GROWTH>0</ACCOUNT_GROWTH>
                           <PRODUCT_GROWTH>0</PRODUCT_GROWTH>
                           </period_sid>
                           </period>

30002                      Same like above
```

I am new to `XML` so couldn't able to do it quickly. I have used [Marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564541/how-to-convert-records-in-a-table-to-xml-format-using-t-sql?rq=1) solution with `cross apply` but can't able to achieve it.

Note: my major goal is, in above image if we see there are three records for single ccp_details_sid so I want to convert it as one row by using `XML` (mentioned above).

Comment: A good question! I appreciate the *copy'n'pasteable* script! +1 from my side

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following will work for you:

```
SELECT  t.CCP_DETAILS_SID,
        (   SELECT  PERIOD_SID AS [@period_sid],
                    x.PROJECTION_SALES,
                    x.PROJECTION_UNITS,
                    x.ACCOUNT_GROWTH,
                    x.PRODUCT_GROWTH
            FROM    #Example AS x
            WHERE   x.CCP_DETAILS_SID = t.CCP_DETAILS_SID
            FOR XML PATH('period_sid'), TYPE, ROOT('period')
        ) AS xml_format_string
FROM    #Example AS t
GROUP BY t.CCP_DETAILS_SID;
```

It essentially gets all your unique values for `CCP_DETAILS_SID` using:

```
SELECT  t.CCP_DETAILS_SID
FROM    #Example AS t
GROUP BY t.CCP_DETAILS_SID;
```

Then for each of these values uses the correlated subquery to form the XML. With the key points being:

- Use `@` in front of the alias to create a property, e.g. `AS [@period_sid]`
- Use `PATH('period_sid')` to name the container for each row
- Use `ROOT('period')` to name the outer nodes.

**[Example on DBFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f6da925a8b14162833f058ffff890245)**