# Convert from SQL to XML wuthout having multiple tags

Tags: mysql, xml

Im pretty new to XML usage, im trying to achieve something like what was asked on this question here
[Converting rows to XML format in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840730/converting-rows-to-xml-format-in-sql-server)
But instead of having `<tag1>value<\tag1>` I need the output to be `<tag1=value>`, so using the original example the output would be something like
`<period_sid period_sid=1802 PROJECTION_SALES=1595642.121 PROJECTION_UNITS=18834.75725 ACCOUNT_GROWTH=0 PRODUCT_GROWTH=0\>`

From what I know, what I need is similar to XML AUTO on SQL servers, but I cant seem to find an equivalent on mYSQL.

Sorry if this is not the propper way of asking, its my very first time using the site :P

Comment: I am unaware of any XML standards that allow you to omit the closing tag and use the tag itself to contain a value. In theory and in practice what you are trying to accomplish is to NOT use XML while using XML. You may get better help if you explain Why you're trying to accomplish this. Key=Value is a standard in every data storage facility. SQL has "field=value" XML has <field>value</field> by definition, but also allows <container field=value>value2</container>. So knowing the background may be Very Useful.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? Please correct tags. It sounds like you just want attribute-centric XML. Please show your sample data and expected output

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Will update the post once Im home, I dont have access to the system right now. I corrected the tags since the server its a mysql server (my mistake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following (note that the entire attributes `a1=""` through `a5=""` are being replaced, not just their values)...

```sql
create table Period (
  period_sid int,
  PROJECTION_SALES decimal(18, 3),
  PROJECTION_UNITS decimal(18,5),
  ACCOUNT_GROWTH int,
  PRODUCT_GROWTH int
);

insert Period
  (period_sid, PROJECTION_SALES, PROJECTION_UNITS, ACCOUNT_GROWTH, PRODUCT_GROWTH)
values
  (1802, 1595642.121, 18834.75725, 0, 0);

select
  UpdateXML(UpdateXML(UpdateXML(UpdateXML(UpdateXML(
    '<period_sid a1="" a2="" a3="" a4="" a5="" />',
      'period_sid/@a1', concat('period_sid="', period_sid, '"')),
      'period_sid/@a2', concat('PROJECTION_SALES="', Projection_Sales, '"')),
      'period_sid/@a3', concat('PROJECTION_UNITS="', PROJECTION_UNITS, '"')),
      'period_sid/@a4', concat('ACCOUNT_GROWTH="', ACCOUNT_GROWTH, '"')),
      'period_sid/@a5', concat('PRODUCT_GROWTH="', PRODUCT_GROWTH, '"'))
    as 'Demo'
from Period;
```

Which yields the output:

```xml
<period_sid period_sid="1802" PROJECTION_SALES="1595642.121" PROJECTION_UNITS="18834.75725" ACCOUNT_GROWTH="0" PRODUCT_GROWTH="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

### Valid for SQL Server, before Question tags were changed

**It looks like you want attribute-centric results, using `FOR XML`**

You can either use `FOR XML PATH` with an `@` sign before each column:

```sql
SELECT
  period_sid AS [@period_sid],
  PROJECTION_SALES AS [@PROJECTION_SALES],
  PROJECTION_UNITS AS [@PROJECTION_UNITS],
  ACCOUNT_GROWTH AS [@ACCOUNT_GROWTH],
  PRODUCT_GROWTH AS [@PRODUCT_GROWTH]
FROM period
FOR XML PATH('period_sid');
```

Or you can use `FOR XML AUTO`, however this syntax has less customization possibilities

```
SELECT
  period_sid,
  PROJECTION_SALES,
  PROJECTION_UNITS,
  ACCOUNT_GROWTH,
  PRODUCT_GROWTH
FROM period AS period_sid
FOR XML AUTO;
```

| Result |
| --- |
| <period_sid period_sid="1802" PROJECTION_SALES="1595642.121000000" PROJECTION_UNITS="18834.757250000" ACCOUNT_GROWTH="0.000000000" PRODUCT_GROWTH="0.000000000"/> |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df4e85f5732472917c06dd5102505898)